# objcopy -add-section equivalent for windows

Tags: windows, dll, exe, code-injection, portable-executable

I'm searching a way to embed custom text file into PE binary. (should be called from batch script)
On linux for ELF files it could be done with objcopy command:

```
objcopy --add-section .sectionName=data.txt --set-section-flags .sectionName=readonly,noload libname.so libnewname.so
```

Is there any tool to achieve the same result?
I've tried EDITBIN utility from VS, but it's not adding a new section, but modifies existing ones.

Comment: In Windows you usually use [Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=msvc-160) to add extra resource files to a PE file.

Comment: Hi @ssbssa, so I have have already built, functioning libraries and executables and need to add them notes ( encrypted TXT file with lots of data which acquired AFTER building them). How to inject that data into the PE file and then parse it back? My idea is to have a section and dump the data, like I do it on linux.